# Wanted to set the value for username and password but unable to do so. Pls help me out here

Tags: selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9Q7k.png)

I tried using below xpath, which is able to inspect the element but doesn't pass the key into it.

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Signin")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(2000);  
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='login']//form//fieldset[1]")).SendKeys("Iris123");                  
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='login']//form//fieldset[2]")).SendKeys("Iris!@#");
```

Comment: Please refer attached picture for GUI information.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is incorrect try using this instead.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="load_form"]/fieldset[1]/input")).SendKeys("Iris123");
```